# imported stylesheets not working after adding react-native-navigation

Tags: android, react-native, stylesheet, react-native-navigation

I've recently added react-native-navigation to my project, and now I can't get imported stylesheet to work. What I'm trying to do is this:

```
import screenstyles from './screenstyles';

class Screen extends Component {

 render() {
   return (
     <View style={screenstyles.container}>
       <Text style={screenstyles.basictext}>Text I want to display</Text>
     </View>
  );
 }
```

screenstyles.js:

```
import EStyleSheet from 'react-native-extended-stylesheet';

export default EStyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '$primaryBlue'
  },
  basictext: {
    color: "#fff",
    fontSize: 34
  }
});
```

But I simply get a default white screen with unstyled text.

The only way I get any sort of imported styling to work at the moment is by doing this

```
import {Container, styles} from '../components/Container';

  class Screen extends Component {

    render() {
       return (
         <Container backgroundColor={"red"}>
         </Container>
     );
  }
}
```

Container.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'blue'
  },
  text: {
    color: '#fff',
    fontSize: 30,
    fontWeight: '500'
  }

});

const Container = ({onPress, backgroundColor, texttest}) => (
  <View style={[styles.container, {backgroundColor}]}>
    <Text style={styles.text}></Text>
  </View>
);

export default Container;
```

This approach isn't the best because it makes it much more difficult to use the same stylesheet for each screen but still being able to customize the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Try rewriting the screenstyles.js file as follows:

```
const React = require('react-native-extended-stylesheet');
const { EStyleSheet } = React;

var styles =  EStyleSheet.create({
   container: {
      flex: 1,
      alignItems: 'center',
      justifyContent: 'center',
      backgroundColor: '$primaryBlue'
   },
   basictext: {
      color: "#fff",
      fontSize: 34
   }
});

module.exports = styles;
```